# Tools to make TFS 2010 Build customization easy

Tags: build-automation, workflow-foundation, tfsbuild

Are there any visual tools for the TFS2010 Build engine?

I just don't need to know WorkFlowright right now.

It would be nice to just pickup a tool and make my custom builds rather than digging into WorkFlow, then into TFS 2010's way of using WorkFlow.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out the product [FinalBuilder](http://www.finalbuilder.com/team-foundation-server.aspx).  It has built in support for creating TFS Builds using the FinalBuilder UI and actions.

Hope this helps.